# Automatic External Hard Drive Mount

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I've been having problems with an external drive that doesn't mount automatically on Ubuntu but mounts fine only on Windows.

I normally have to manually mount it.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you use the server edition, the drive will not mount automatically.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB, for info about mounting the drive!